# Send lp tokens to burn address

Tags: solidity, pancakeswap, liquidity-provider, sushiswap

is there any repo or links where I can learn how to burn lp tokens? If someone added liquidity I want the contract itself to burn the lp tokens instead of sending them to a user.

Answer (score 0):

It's rather difficult to prevent someone from adding liquidity to a pair, since that functionality is mostly at the exchange's end.

Anyway, to burn any tokens, you have two options:

1. If the token contract includes `burn` functionality, use that. In that case the tokens are truly burned and removed from the total supply
2. If there is no such functionality, the standard is to send the tokens to some address from which they can't be recovered. Basically any address will do (unless you know someone has its private key or the address already has transactions). But to be more obvious about it, often `0x0` address or something like `0x0dead` are used. The point is that it's very unlikely for anyone to ever find the private key for any single address, so the tokens are considered lost or burned - although not removed from the token's total supply.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you are talking about if someone added liquidity to an already existing DEX (such as uniswap or PCS), then i am pretty sure you have no way to do that. If you are making your own  dex though this is trivial.